# How can I eliminate all space between block divs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

In the fiddle below, I've created a 16x16 table using jQuery. 
table fiddle

Here is the CSS:

```
td {
width: 30px;
height: 30px;
background-color: blue;
border: 1px solid red;
display: inline-block;
}
```

And here is the jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('body').append('<table></table>')
    for (var i=1; i<=16; i++) {
        $('table').append('<tr></tr>');
        for (var j=1; j<=16; j++) {
            $('table:nth-last-child(1)').append('<td></td>');
        }
    }
});
```

As it stands, there is white space between each row of the table, and I would like to remove it. Can anyone offer advice on how to achieve this?

Things I've tried:

1. A `reset.css` file.
2. Using divs instead of a table (see this other fiddle or the alternate jquery below (CSS same as before but targeting has been changed to `.container`)

   ```
   $(document).ready(function() {
       for (var i=1; i<=16; i++) {
           $('body').append('<div class="row"></div>');
           for (var j=1; j<=16; j++) {
               $('body:nth-last-child(1)').append('<div class="container"></div>');
           }
       }
   });
   ```

So, can anyone help me remove the white space?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Part of the problem is that you're appending `<td>` to the `<table>` and not to the `<tr>`.
Also, you should use `border-collapse: collapse;` to eliminate default borders from the table.

Here is a working example :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('body').append('<table></table>')
    for (var i=1; i<=16; i++) {
        $('table').append('<tr></tr>');
        for (var j=1; j<=16; j++) {
            $('table tr:nth-last-child(1)').append('<td></td>');
        }
    }
});
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
td {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: blue;
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Alternate example with `<div>`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  for (var i = 1; i <= 16; i++) {
    var $row = $('<div />')
      .addClass('row');
    $('body').append($row);
    for (var j = 1; j <= 16; j++) {
      $row.append('<div class="container"></div>');
    }
  }
});
```

```css
div.row {
  clear: both;
}

div.container {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background: #ccc;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Super, that's solved it. Thank you also for clarifying my understanding of how `nth-child` selectors work.

Comment: Any advice on how I'd achieve a similar effect with two `display: block` elements as in my alternate example?

Comment: Thanks! I'm guessing it's the `.addClass('row')` line which removes the space, as aside from that I can't see a significant difference from my own attempts?

Comment: @adc the `.addClass('row')` is similar to your own `('<div class="row"></div>')`, just another way to do it. The important part is in the CSS, I used `clear: both;` on `.row` to make sure each row is on a different line, and `float: left;` on `.container` to display every grid item side by side. You could also use `display: inline-block;` instead of `float: left;`.